# Can a flyback converter make 220VDC?

Tags: switches, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inverter, rectifier

I am making an inverter for a 40W three phase induction motor.

To control motor speed, I currently use a [FNA41560T2 inverter driver](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/power-modules/intelligent-power-modules-ipms/fna41560t2#overview) from an STM32F103RB development board.

That part of the solution works perfectly for me, but I can't find a 220VDC power supply to feed into it, at least not in South Korea.

I have already constructed a simple high voltage DC power supply using a diode bridge, capacitor, and isolated transformer, a circuit which looks like this:

[image]

This solution works, but the 60VA transformer size is too large.

[image]

Because I need a smaller solution, I now believe that what I need is an SMPS to make 220VDC, perhaps a flyback converter that might look something like this:

[image]

The above circuit works fine in simulation but in real life, I know that it can't be that simple. It must need many more things that I don't know about.

My ability to build a power circuit is almost zero, but maybe I can make it with your advice, like the motor control circuit.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? I've made a 200V DC step-up converter from 24V (to store energy in a cheap, but high votlage capacitor). But that was a standard SMPS, boost typology, as we didn't need it to be isolated.

Comment: _”My knowledge to build power circuit is almost zero.”_ A mains connected SMPS is no small task. I was going to say “just buy one from outside of Korea”, but 220 V DC was indeed an oddity despite being a somewhat standard DC supply rail from battery systems. Perhaps look into connecting two or four in series to get the correct voltage? Settle with slightly higher and let your motor PWM inverter adjust accordingly?

Comment: Why does the motor have to be so specific?

Comment: Puffafish//my design must contain "isolation". Well, its good work simple dedign offer enough design, i want it safe.

Comment: winny//my motor rating voltage(line voltage) is 220V. its ok if voltage is lower then 220V. Indeed, i dont want voltage doubler or qudrature thing. Thats too much size for me.

Comment: Sure, but do you have a motor driver between your 220 V DC supply and the motor?

Comment: Yor pictures don't seem to agree with each other or your request. First pic calcs as 124W out (220VDC into 390 ohms). Your second pic is worse, 220VDC into 15 ohms which is more than 3kw. I'm expecting maybe 100W of 220VDC eventually ending up as 40W at the motor. So I'm expecting a converter needed for 240VAC at the wall into 100W of 220VDC into your FNA41560T2 solution. Please give a pic representative of the whole power train, from wall to motor, with approximate volts and currents at each stage, assuming 75% efficiency at each conversion. Help us to help you.